# How can I insert a sessionStorage variable in an SQL db?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sessionstorage

I am trying to get a sessionStorage in my db but nothing gets inserted.

My code is as following:

```
window.onload = function (){        
            doit.db = openDatabase('takenlijst V0.8', '1.0', 'takenlijst database', 2 * 1024 * 1024); 

            doit.db.transaction (function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taak (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , sID INTEGER, taak, datum, conditie);'); 
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS segment (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , naam);'); 
                    });

            document.getElementById("knopInvoeren").onclick = tInvoer; 

};


var tInvoer = function (){  

            var datum = new Date();
            var taak = document.getElementById("taakInvoer").value;
            var conditie = 0;
            var sID = sessionStorage.sMenuID;

            doit.db.transaction(function (tx) {     

                alert(""+ sessionStorage.sMenuID +"");

                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO taak ("+sessionStorage.sMenuID+", taak, datum, conditie) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", [sID, taak, datum, conditie]); 

                }); 
            vulGegevens();
            ophalen(sessionStorage.sMenuID);
        };
```

When I alert the sessionStorage I get the right value but when I try to INSERT the query, nothing happens.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes it sais:

Uncaught ReferenceError: sID is not defined 
(anonymous function)

In the rule of INSERT INTO

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using simply :

> tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO taak (sID, taak, datum, conditie) VALUES
>   (?, ?, ?, ?);", [sID, taak, datum, conditie]);

I don't understand why you're trying to provide an evaluated value in the definition part of your SQL query.